# Put two child divs next to each other inside parrent div

Tags: html, css

that's what I got so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/cHKF4/3/

But I want to put small boxes (box1 and box2 inside late)

```
#late {
    position: relative;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: #00fff3;
    height: 200px;
       width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#box1 {
    position: relative;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #55fff3;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#box2 {
    position: relative;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: #55fff3;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/cHKF4/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Is this what you're trying to achieve](http://jsfiddle.net/cHKF4/7/) (`box1` and `box2` side by side and centred inside `late` with `late` centred on the page)  :

```
<div id="late">
    <div id="inner">
       <div id="box1"></div>
       <div id="box2"></div>
    </div>
</div>​

#late {
    border: solid 3px #00fff3;
    height: 200px;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
}

#inner {
    width: 408px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

#box1 {
    border: solid 1px #55fff3;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

#box2 {
    border: solid 3px #55fff3;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
​
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to center #box1 and #box2 inside #late?

If you are just trying to put them side by side inside #late this is how I would do it: http://codepen.io/AntonNiklasson/pen/rIdcj

Answer (score 1):

Add `float:left` to both `#box1` and `#box2`

```
#box1 {
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: #55fff3;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
}

#box2 {
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: #55fff3;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#box1 {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 10px;
}
```

Keep the parent container's position set to relative.